# cmd Text Search & Print

Tags: sorting, text, cmd

I've been tasked with extracting some data from a text file and I was wondering if anyone knows a quick cmd method to my problem.

The file I need to search is quite large, consisting of repetitive records.
What I'm looking to do is search for one line of text, say:
'searchForThisLineOfText'

Then, when it's found, go to the next line down from that text, and write that line to a file.

So the contents of the file looks somting like this:

**searchForThisLineOfText**

**563473**

someOtherLine

34583933

anotherline

2342

**searchForThisLineOfText**

**3424**

someOtherLine

34583933

anotherline

2342

From that, I would like to write the numbers **563473** and **3424** to a file.

Anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "found="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25871330.txt) DO (
  IF DEFINED found ECHO %%a
  IF "%%a"=="searchForThisLineOfText" (SET "found=Y") ELSE (SET "found=")
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25871330.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the blank lines are not actually in the text file.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" | findrepl "searchForThisLineOfText" /o:1:1 >"newfile.txt"
pause
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - unfortunately, I'm not in a position to download files from external sites at the moment - so I can't use your solution in this case.

Comment: Get `findrepl.bat` from this forum instead: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a temporary file with the number of the lines that need to be retrieved and then retrieves the required lines

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem We will need a temporary file
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    rem Get the number of the lines that we need to retrieve
    (
        for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('
            findstr /n /l /c:"searchText" "data.txt"
        ') do ( set /a "n=%%a+1" & echo(!n!:)
    )>"%tempFile%" 

    rem Retrieve the indicated lines to the output file
    (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
            findstr /n /r /c:"^" "data.txt" 
            ^| findstr /b /l /g:"%tempFile%"
        ') do echo(%%b
    )>"outputFile.txt"

    rem Remove the temporary file
    del "%tempFile%" > nul 2>nul
```